# Problem mapping new api controller added to Razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core, razor

I have tried adding an API controller to a Razor pages project in .Net core. I added a Controllers folder to my project, clicked on add item and chose new controller. The pages run on the local host but when I tried testing the default GET using

```
https://localhost:44348/api/
```

in Postman, I get a 404 error.

The code Visual Studio generated was:

```
namespace MyWebApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class APIController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/<APIController>
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<APIController>/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<APIController>
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

(I've removed the PUT and DELETE methods). I am not sure how this is mapped.

I assume that the API is running on the same port as the rest of the app. Is this correct?

In the mapping "api/[controller]", what should I be putting for [controller]. Do I need to instantiate an APIController object somewhere?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try `https://localhost:44348/api/api`?

Comment: I can see what you are implying - as the controller is called 'APIcontroller' I should use the 'api' prefix for controller. Makes sense but unfortunately it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an API Controller in razor page project,you can do like this:

startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            ...

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

And then if you want to go to `Get`,you need to use `https://localhost:44348/api/API` as `Chetan Ranpariya` said.

Comment: Thanks Yiyi! That fixed the problem!